# Importing a database dump -- PSQL

Tags: macos, postgresql, syntax-error, psql

I am trying to import an old .gz database dump into my database using the terminal. It is a Postgresql environment.

**This is what i am doing:**

psql test < 052710_1.gz

**Responce:**

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "test"
LINE 1: test 
        ^

**I also tried:**

psql --dbname test < --file 052710_1.gz

psql -d test -U postgres -f 052710_1.gz

And they both gave me the same error.
I have tried using the .exe on the end of psql and it has the same issue.

I am running Postgresql 10.1

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html#BACKUP-DUMP-LARGE

Comment: How was the file `052710_1.gz` generated?

Comment: apparently it was created with a database dump back in 2010

Comment: also when i try to use the cat command it is the same error as above. Could it have to do with how my Postgres was installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of version 10.1

try using the following command

**pg_restore -d test < 052710_1.gz**

Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the commands. Hope it will works.

```
sudo psql -U postgres
 create database temp_databse;
 exit
```

Execute following command

```
psql -U postgres temp_database < extracted_database_file_name
```

Above command will restore database...